# Let $\Omega$ be an opened set in $\mathbb{C}$, prove that $K_{l}$ is compact in $\mathbb{C}$.

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm trying to prove the following problem:

Let $\Omega$ be an opened set in $\mathbb{C}$. For every positive integer $l$, we set $K_{l}:=\left \{ z \in \Omega: \left | z \right |\leq l \:  \text{and}\, d\left ( z,\mathbb{C} \setminus \Omega \right ) \geq \frac{1}{l}\right \}$ where $d\left ( z,\mathbb{C} \setminus \Omega \right )$ is the distance from $z$ to the set $ \mathbb{C} \setminus \Omega$.

Prove that $K_{l}$ is compact; $\{K_{l}\}_{l}$ is an increasing sequence; and $\Omega=\bigcup_{l=1}^{\infty}K_{l}$.

My plan: Prove $K_{l}$ is closed and bounded. Clearly, $K_l$ is bounded since $K_l$ is contained in the closed disk centered at $0$ with the radius $r=l$ by its definition. But I'm still stuck on proving it is a closed set.

It's great to get your suggestions.

Comment: $z \to d(z,\mathbb C\setminus \Omega)$ is a continuous function.

Comment: @geetha290krm Ahh I got that! Thanks!